# Why polygon not displayed on the map?

Tags: gis, openlayers

I want to draw a polygon on the map using OpenLayers 6. Here how I did it using openlayers 2 and it works perfect:

```
return new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(pointsArr)]);
```

Here how I try to do it in OpenLayers 6:

```
   function getShapeObject(raw) {
    var coordinates = [];
    raw.GeometryHlp.StrPoints.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
        coordinates.push([item.X, item.Y]);
    });
        return new LinearRing(coordinates);
    }
```

where is coordinates is array that looks like this:`([x,y],[x1,y1],[x2,y2]...)`

When I try to draw a polygon on open layers 6 the polygon is not displayed, and I don't get any errors in the console.

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? Why polygon is not displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot display a LinearRing.  Use another pair of `[]` and create a Polygon:

```
return new Polygon([coordinates]);
```